# What is the best way to view google pagespeed grade?

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed

The google pagespeed test will give results in json format, my question is that is there any good open source viewer program to visualize the result?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PageSpeed has two browser extensions for Chrome and Firefox which run the same test as the online API, and also provide a lot of extra tips and explanations: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights_extensions

The code behind both is open-source, so you can pull out the bits as needed.